Google Docs Apps Script Extension Add-ons - Greyed Out after Installation
I have retrieved necessary permissions from my admin to publish my Apps Script Extension to the internal Google Martketplace. (You can imagine it to be something similar to the tutorial here)
When developing/testing the extension, I was able to use it just fine. 
After installing it "officially" via the Google Marketplace, the extension becomes greyed out.



What's happening to my app?
I have also provided all the necessary oauth scopes in appsscript.json:
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  ],


Please add a [mcve].

Your admin probably needs to enable it...

Assuming that the setting Allow users to install Google Docs add-ons from add-ons store. is enabled under Features and Applications since it was mentioned that the issue happens After installing it "officially" via the Google Marketplace. I'd recommend allowlisting the application on Google Workspace Marketplace apps and observe if it'll work.

added the tutorial i was trying, and some screenshot that show my admin has enabled me to install add ons and to also publish the app

The updated screenshots (2nd from top) above from my admin shows the allow list already in place

Still following @Saddle's comment, also check that 'Allow users to install Google Docs add-ons from add-ons store' is enabled. You can also try checking out this article to further confirm that you have published your add-on correctly. https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish

Everything seems to be in order based on what you provided. The only thing I'd like to confirm is if you're a user of the organizational unit where Allowlist Access has been set since it's only Allowed for 1 organizational unit. If you are, consider removing your account and re-adding it because there are times that doing that fixes these types of issues.

Have you installed the add-on in your account or you are opening the document containing the Apps Script project for your add-on?

It turns out that "Allow list" was insufficient; this app needs to be added to the "domain install" list in Google workspace by the admin instead. After doing the latter the app was accessible
